# Longest Increasing Sub-sequence such that last-First element in LIS is maximum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

How to find the difference between the last and first element of the longest increasing sub-sequence such that value of (last element - first element) in LIS is maximum ?

Comment: question is not clear to me. suppose we have 1,100,0,1,2,3,4,5,6 then what is the answer? 1,100 or 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: @SaeedAmiri here answer should be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: @domen  am trying it with a DP soluiton, where at index i th it stores value till that current idex with the maximum length and the largest value ending at posiiton i th.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a standard dynamic programming solution where we define `f[i]` as the longest increasing subsequence ending in the `i-th` element. We can store a pair `(max length, smallest first element)` for each `i` instead. One can show that it leads to a correct global solution (intuitively, it's correct as it still stores an optimal solution for all subsequences ending in a specific element and the fact that one prefix is "better" than the other means that the overall subsequence is better).

You can also make it `O(N log N)` by storing this pairs in an efficient data structure (like a segment tree) if the performance requirements are high.

Answer (score 0):

Very naive algorithm is as follows:

1. In the first pass find all maximal consecutive subsequences and their length maintain the maximum length (just maintain the number for this).
2. In the second pass find the start and end differences of all sequences of maximum length and output the one which is maximum among all of them.

All this is in O (n), it is possible to do it in one pass. Just to simplify it I break it down into two steps.